# Model validation is not working in Partial View

Tags: model-view-controller

Hi All I am very new in MVC . So Please Help Me

My Question is .. I am using Partial View as below

```
 @model IELTS_TEST.Models.StatusMaster @{
     Layout = null; } <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> <script
 src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> <script
 src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Status", "POST")) {
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
        <legend>Create New Status</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.STATUSDESC)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.STATUSDESC)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.STATUSDESC)
        </div>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" id="btnSave" name="Command" value="Save" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only">
                <span class="ui-button-text">Save</span></button>
            </p>
        </fieldset> }

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Close", "StatusMaster") </div>
```

and my controller look like

```
public ActionResult CreateStatus()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                ViewBag.IsUpdate = false;
                return View("_Create");
            }
            else
                return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(IELTS_TEST.Models.StatusMaster objStatusMaster, String Command)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return PartialView("_Create", objStatusMaster);
            }
            else
            {
                if (IELTS_TEST.Models.StatusMaster.SaveStatus(objStatusMaster))
                {
                    TempData["Msg"] = "Status added succeessfully";
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    return RedirectToAction("StatusMaster", "Status");
                }

            }
            return PartialView("_Create", objStatusMaster);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

and the model class is ...

`

```
public class StatusMaster
        {
            public int statusid { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Provide Status Description!")]
            [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Status Description cannot be more than 50 characters long!")]
            [Display(Name = "Status Description")]
            public string statusdesc { get; set; }


            public int makerid { get; set; }
            public DateTime makerdate { get; set; }
            public int modiid{ get; set; }
            public DateTime modefieddate{ get; set; }
    }`
```

So My Partial view is opened as Popup ...

But the problem is No Model Validation is perform in client side..

Page goes to server side and popup does not exists any more in the page

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to use the correct overload for the begin form method as given here
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460344(v=vs.118).aspx

It should be `beginform("create","status ",FormMethod.Post)`

2. I would suggest that you use a HTML.ajaxform or use custom jQuery ajax to post the data so that the popup model can still be in place.
3. As a good development practice, do not throw any exception from the controller, handle the exception, log it and add a friendly message to the end user. Or change the controller base class to your derived base controller which takes care of handling unhandled exceptions.

HTH